# Simple HTML form input field with multiple values from barcode scanner

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I know barcode scanner is just another keyboard that sends keycode 13 after every scan, I have a very simple form with just one input field, I want to be able to scan multiple barcodes and click submit to POST data. I think I would would need a javascript for this, but I am no good with javascripts.

The end result would look something like this. You can see multiple barcodes have been scanned and they appear at the bottom of the picture.

The goal is to scan desired number of barcodes without touching the keyboard, when done scanning press the submit button with the click of mouse. When I click submit they should be posted to another page.

[image]

I am sure this is a simple thing for someone who is good at javascript.

Here is the HTML form code.

```
<form action="myform5.php" method="post">
   <p>First name: <input type="text" name="serial" /></p>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

My question is how I can make it do what I described above?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```js
var codes = "";
var codes_el = document.getElementById('codes');
var output_el = document.getElementById('output');

function process_key(event){
  
  var letter = event.key;
  
  if (letter === 'Enter'){
    event.preventDefault();
    letter = "\n";
    event.target.value = "";
  }
  
  // match numbers and letters for barcode
  if (letter.match(/^[a-z0-9]$/gi)){
    codes += letter;
  }
  
  
  codes_el.value = codes;
  output_el.innerHTML = codes;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="myform5.php">
  <input onkeydown="process_key(event)" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
  <input type="hidden" name="codes" id="codes" />
</form>

<pre id="output">
</pre>
```

Then you can get in `myform5.php` like so:

```
<?php
// codes will be a string of barcodes seperated by "\n"
$codes = $_POST['codes'];

// get as array like so
$barcodes = explode("\n", $codes);

// build up string of barcodes
$barcode_str = "";
$prefix = '';
foreach ($barcodes as $barcode){
    $barcode_str .= $prefix . "'" . $barcode . "'";
    $prefix = ', ';
}

$query = "select * from hdds where serial IN (" . $barcode_str . ");";

/* do things with query here */

// once your done processing
// redirect the user back to the form page
header("Location: FormPage.html");
?>
```

I assume your barcodes are strings in the DB.

So you have to wrap each of the barcodes in the query.

Comment: You are right, this should work. But I want to avoid a textarea input box.
It does not look very professional. Please can you help me achieve whats shown in the picture above?

Comment: Is this more like what you were thinking?

Comment: I have tried above, but it does not work at all. I really appreciate your help. Can you look at your code please?

Comment: This is very strange, the code above works here as "Run code Snippet" but when I run on my environment it does not work. Any clues?

Comment: Do you see any js errors in the console? I think it will be because the above js needs to run AFTER the html has all loaded... you need to hook into `document.onload` and then run above js.

Comment: You are a star, it is now working, I was just using <script> I have changed it to <script type="text/javascript"> and it now works.

Comment: Phil, one more question, how can I use this array in php mysql query. I have tried using both implode, explode and join like this, $barcode = explode(", ", $codes);
$barcodes = implode(", ", $codes);
$ids = join("','",$codes);
select * from hdds where serial IN ('$barcode');

Comment: i've added building up the `SELECT` query.

Comment: Phil, thats what I get, PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in /var/www/html/2.php on line, barcodes in DB are stored as plain text string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132544/discussion-between-phil-poore-and-user2107349).